# How does Only A Test affect the end-of-round honor bonuses/penalties?

Tags: ninja-burger

In Ninja Burger, you can play the card *Only A Test* in response to failing a mission; it turns out that your manager was just testing you, and does not blame you for failing.

How does that affect the end-of-round honor bonuses and penalties? There's normally an extra Honor penalty if only one person fails, and there's an honor bonus if *everyone* succeeds. If *Only A Test* hid your failure, can you prevent everyone from getting the honor bonus if everyone else succeeded? Similarly, if your "test" is the only failure, do you lose the "additional" Honor even if you didn't lose Honor for failing the mission?

EDIT: Full text of *Only A Test:*

```
Play this card immediately after you fail a mission. It was only a test! You suffer
no loss of Honor or other penalties. Your manager made the task very difficult in order
to evaluate you and sharpen your skills, and he does not blame you for failing.
You cannot use this card to save yourself from a failed Errand!
```

Comment: What is the exact text of "Only A Test"? This question isn't covered in the [FAQ](http://www.sjgames.com/ninjaburger/faq.html), and I am unable to find an image or exact rules text anywhere on [SJG](http://forums.sjgames.com/forumdisplay.php?f=30).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only a Test** has you treat a failure as if you didn't fail. If you were the only failure, and **Only a Test** was played on your "failure," everyone would receive an honor bonus (+1 Honor) and you would not receive the additional (-1 honor) penality for being the only "failure." A moderator on [SJG Forum](http://forums.sjgames.com/showpost.php?p=1541639&postcount=2) said:

> You still fail, the manager just kinda hides the fact. **So, in the context of the game, you did not fail. And yes, it will affect the game that way.**

Comment: So that makes it equivalent to the way my group played *Order Cancelled* (except that *Order Cancelled* is played before the mission, not after it). It's straightforward, at least!